# sc.exe is not recognized while in a batch file

Tags: mongodb, batch-file, client-server

This is the code we have to use to build this batch file which will connect to the servers we will be using for MongoDB. **** is my username account and do not want to share it with anyone.

```
sc.exe create MongoDB binPath = 
"C:\Users\****\Desktop\FanshaweCollege\semester3\Servers\bin\mongod.exe 
--service --config=\"C:\Users\****\Desktop\FanshaweCollege\semester3\Servers\mongodb.cfg\"" 
DisplayName= "MongoDB" start= "auto"
```

The teacher will not help us and he has no clue what the problem is. I started to search through google, but the only things I can find on the matter is I need to change the  environment variables, and it is set to all.

The Error is:

```
 'sc.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How am I able to get this working

Comment: `where sc.exe` command should return `C:\Windows\System32\sc.exe`. Otherwise, you have changed `%path%` environment variable incorrectly by using either `path` command or `set path=something` command or  `SystemPropertiesAdvanced` [Windows GUI](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) or via improper registry manipulation? Check `where /R C:\ sc.exe` to ensure you didn't delete `sc.exe` accidentally...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `where sc.exe` to search where is it. then use the full path of that command.

```
sc.exe create MongoDB binPath = "C:\Users\****\Desktop\FanshaweCollege\semester3\Servers\bin\mongod.exe 
--service --config=\"C:\Users\****\Desktop\FanshaweCollege\semester3\Servers\mongodb.cfg\"" 
DisplayName= "MongoDB" start= "auto"
```

You have to deal with double/single quotes (`"` and `'`). Not sure you can do this with \ in path because in your example it can be interpreted as a folder. try caret (`^`) instead or single quote inside double quotes

In your example, the correct syntaxe should be:

```
C:\Windows\System32\sc.exe create MongoDB ^
    binPath="'C:\*****\mongod.exe' --service --config=^
    'C:\Users\****\Desktop\FanshaweCollege\semester3\Servers\mongodb.cfg'" ^
    DisplayName="MongoDB" start="auto"
```

*Note: Here carets (`^`) are to escape carriages return.*

Or in one line:

```
C:\Windows\System32\sc.exe create MongoDB binPath="'C:\*****\mongod.exe' --service --config='C:\Users\****\Desktop\FanshaweCollege\semester3\Servers\mongodb.cfg'" DisplayName="MongoDB" start="auto"
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the location of sc.exe to environment variable "Path"